# Firefox addon : DOMWindowUtils.sendKeyEvent misbehaving

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I am writing a Firefox addon and have a need to programmatically generate key events, and have the browser carry out all actions it would do as if user entered those keys.

I am trying using DOMWindowUtils (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMWindowUtils)'s sendKeyEvent. I have found the following issue :

If I generate events like left arrow/right arrow within contentEditable fields, the browser doesn't change cursor position. Why? (Note: If I generate events for chars like 'a', 'b', ... then browser appropriately updates the text within contentEditable area, so there are no obvious flaws in my code). For non contentEditable fields, it behaves as expected.

Sample code that can be executed in Tools->Web Developer->Scratchpad, with environment 'Browser' (code requires chrome privilege).

```
var doc = gBrowser.contentDocument,
    win = doc.defaultView;

var domWindowUtils = win.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                     .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);

var div = doc.getElementById('contentEditableDiv');
div.focus();

['keydown', 'keypress', 'keyup'].forEach(function(type) {
    // if I generate characters like 'a', 'b' they work
    // domWindowUtils.sendKeyEvent(type, 65, 97, 0, 0);

    // 37 is left arrow, 38 right arrow
    domWindowUtils.sendKeyEvent(type, 37, 0, 0, 0);    
});
```

I tried using `initEvent/dispatchEvent` but exhibits the same result.

Is there a way I can reliably generate events and have the browser carry out all actions?

Answer (score 0):

Read again the meaning of the return value, it is true when the default action was **not** prevented.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question based on this info. But the core question still remains, why am I not getting the default behavior of moving the cursor/caret when I generate events related to arrow keys?